# Angular 2 changing disabled/enabled select options

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I'm using Angular2 and I have 2 selects:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
<form name="myForm">
<label for="companySelect"> Company: </label>
<select name="companySelect" id="companySelect">
  <option *ngFor="let company of companies" 
           value="{{company.id}}"> {{company.name}}
  </option>
</select>

<label for="documentTypeSelect"> Type: </label>
<select name="documentTypeSelect" id="documentTypeSelect">
  <option value="type1">type1</option>
  <option value="type2">type2</option>
  <option  value="type3">type3</option>
</select>
 </form>
 <hr>
</div>
```

I want to change second select options depending on the first select. I can get types (boolean value) by using

> company.companyRelations.pop().type1
>
> company.companyRelations.pop().type2

And now, if for example type1 is false, the option in second select should be disabled and if type2 is true, option should be enabled. Is that possible?

EDIT:

Companies in select have deasdv, invoic and orders properties which are true or false. How can i now pass these properties into component.ts properties? Is it possible by event or what? I want to get for example

> company.companyRelations.pop().desadv

For company which is selected and it will change disabled options in the second one.

> html

```
<form name="myForm">
<label for="companySelect"> Company: </label>
<select class="form-control" name="companySelect" id="companySelect" 
 [(ngModel)]="companySelect" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
  <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled  selected>Select...</option>
  <option *ngFor="let company of companies" [ngValue]="company.id">
 {{company.name}}</option>
</select>

<select  name="documentTypeSelect" id="documentTypeSelect">
  <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled  selected>Select...</option>
  <option [disabled]="!desadv" value="desadv">desadv</option>
  <option [disabled]="!invoic" value="invoic">invoic</option>
  <option  [disabled]="!orders" value="orders">orders</option>
</select>
</form>
```

> component.ts

```
  desadv: boolean = false;
  invoic: boolean = false;
  orders: boolean = false;
```

and here it will be something like:

```
  onChange(event) {
   if(event.desadv) {
     this.desadv = true;
   }
  }
```

My solution:

> html

```
 <form name="myForm">
<label for="companySelect"> Company: </label>
<select name="companySelect" id="companySelect" [(ngModel)]="companySelect" 
(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
  <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled  selected>Select...</option>
  <option *ngFor="let company of companies" [ngValue]="company">
{{company.name}}</option>
</select>

<label for="documentTypeSelect"> Type: </label>
<select  name="documentTypeSelect" id="documentTypeSelect">
  <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled  selected>Select...</option>
  <option [disabled]="!desadv" value="desadv">desadv</option>
  <option [disabled]="!invoic" value="invoic">invoic</option>
  <option  [disabled]="!orders" value="orders">orders</option>
  <option  [disabled]="!recadv" value="orders">recadv</option>
  <option  [disabled]="!shipment" value="orders">shipment</option>
</select>
```

> component.ts

```
 onChange(event) {
this.desadv = event.companyRelations[0].desadv;
this.invoic = event.companyRelations[0].invoic;
this.orders = event.companyRelations[0].orders;
this.recadv = event.companyRelations[0].recadv;
this.shipment = event.companyRelations[0].shipment;
}
```

Comment: if [disabled]="!desadv" it will be enable in the option list. do u want disable **[disabled]="desadv" ** change it

Comment: It has to be disabled on the beginning, and if the company's property is enabled, it will change then, so it's ok.

Comment: Ok, i solved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<select class="form-control" name="companySelect" id="companySelect" [(ngModel)]="companySelect" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
    <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled  selected>Select...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let company of companies" [ngValue]="company.id">{{company.name}}</option>
</select>

<select [disabled]="btnDisable" name="documentTypeSelect" id="documentTypeSelect">
  <option value="type1">type1</option>
  <option value="type2">type2</option>
  <option  value="type3">type3</option>
</select>
```

**component.ts**

```
private companySelect: any;
private btnDisable: boolean = true;

onChange(event) {
    if(event) {
        this.btnDisable = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which post ?@user8558489 answer ?

Comment: The main problem is how to pass selected company as event to onChange and how to get from this company the document type property, for example company.companyRelations.pop().desadv

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. 
I have created a demo in which second drop down will be enabled depending upon the value of flag in first drop down object.

```js
// Code goes here

var myApp = angular.module('plunker',[]);
angular.module('plunker').controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl)
MyCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.items1 = [{
id: 1,
label: 'aLabel',
'flag':true,
subItem: { name: 'aSubItem' }
}, {
id: 2,
label: 'bLabel',
 'flag':false,
subItem: { name: 'bSubItem' }
}];

$scope.items2 = [{
id: 1,
label: 'MyName',
'flag':true,
subItem: { name: 'aSubItem' }
}, {
id: 2,
label: 'YourName',
 'flag':false,
subItem: { name: 'bSubItem' }
}];

$scope.changeDetect = function(){
  $scope.selected1='';
  console.log($scope.selected);
  if($scope.selected.flag)
  {
    $scope.flagValue=false;
  } else {
    $scope.flagValue=true;
  }

}

$scope.flagValue=true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>

<div  ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items1 track by item.id" ng-model="selected" ng-change="changeDetect()"></select>
   
    <select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items2 track by item.id" ng-model="selected1" ng-disabled="flagValue"></select>
   </div>
```

In AngularJS 2

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedDeviceObj" (ngModelChange)="onChangeObj($event)" name="sel3">
    <option [ngValue]="i" *ngFor="let i of deviceObjects">{{i.name}}</option>
  </select>
 <select [ngModel]="selectedDeviceObj1" name="sel2" [disabled]="flag">
    <option [ngValue]="i" *ngFor="let i of deviceObjects1">{{i.name}}</option>
  </select>
onChangeObj(newObj) {
     this.selectedDeviceObj1='';
    console.log(newObj);
    this.selectedDeviceObj = newObj;
     if(newObj.flag){
      this.flag = false;
    }
    else {

      this.flag = true;
    }
```

Please find Demo Link [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/apDhSvZ567uUtbTPF3DL?p=preview)

Comment: Its in angularjs only but not in Angularjs 2.I have updated in Angular 2 also.Please check